# Save Audio Produced by MixerHost Sample on developer.apple

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio, mixing

I get sample of MixerHost from developer.apple and now i want that Mix Sound to save in another audio File, 
  can any one Help me???

Comment: @downVoter can you Please tell me the reason for down Vote????

Comment: @buildsucceeded I think the question is genuine.

Answer (score 0):

Use EXTAudioFileWriteASync to write the contents of the IOBuffer to an audio file object. This can be done in the render callback.

Then when you are done use ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL to save the audio to disk.

Comment: i had follow this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118429/how-to-record-sound-produced-by-mixer-unit-output-ios-core-audio-audio-graph

Comment: but i hv confussion in it can u Guide me

Comment: You can try looking at a similar question I posted a while back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930609/write-audio-to-disk-from-io-unit    It will be very difficult to help you if you dont elaborate your question to be more specific about what in particular you are having difficulty with. Prehaps add code you have tried that does not work

Comment: also a google search of ' remoteio write to disk' will yeild lots of helpful examples.