# Write the output of a Remote IO Audio Unit to a file offline

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

I have a program that generates sound using an AUSampler connected to a Remote IO Audio Unit. The AUSampler is controlled by pre-recorded events that are triggered in a timed loop. I want to write the resulting sound to a file.

There are some other questions on writing to a file in the render callback of the IO unit:

- [Recording to AAC from RemoteIO: data is getting written but file unplayable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113977/recording-to-aac-from-remoteio-data-is-getting-written-but-file-unplayable)
- [How to write output of AUGraph to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951458/how-to-write-output-of-augraph-to-a-file)
- [Recording from RemoteIO: resulting .caf is pitch shifted slower + distorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067117/recording-from-remoteio-resulting-caf-is-pitch-shifted-slower-distorted)
- [Write Audio To Disk From IO Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930609/write-audio-to-disk-from-io-unit)

But these all deal with writing the data in real time. Is there a way to offline render the file in less time it takes than to play it?

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm looking for a solution for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are rendering a pre-recorded sequence, then why not just write raw PCM data to disk? The [ExtAudioFileWriteAsync](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) function should work in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question was misleading. What I meant was that I have a set of "events" that are triggered in a loop; these events will then send MIDI messages to the AUSampler which produces the sound.